# how to remove default blue dropdown color in chrome browser

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

When we click on drop down menu the blue color comes to hover, I want red color when hover, but it is not working in Chrome browser. The CSS class I have used is here:

```
option:checked {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #d4003c inset !important;
    background-color:red;
}
```

It works in Chrome and IE 11 but not in Chrome. please suggest class to change default color of dropdown.

Comment: " *i want red color when hover* ". The CSS selector which implements rules when an element is being hovered is `:hover`, not `:checked`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following `CSS` property:

```
outline-color: red;
```